# Standard deviation in power pivot with filter

Tags: dax, powerpivot

My table looks like this:

```
CPRNR | Man-years | Salary  | Average pay
-----------------------------------------
XXXXX |      0,5  | 100.000 |     200.000
```

[Average pay] is a measure based on [Salary]/[Man-years]. What I want is to get standard deviation for [Average pay].
I've tried the following, but it results in an error.

`=STDEVX.P(DataCSV , [Average pay])`

The error message is:

MdxScript(Model) (6, 34) Calculations error in measure 'DataCSV'[Average pay]: A division by zero has been encountered.

There are 0 values in [Man-years] and for the table I have added a value filter on [Cprnr] ([Man-years] >= 0,825) and I want the standard deviation to only use the values that are left.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid division by zero error there is the [DIVIDE](https://dax.guide/divide/) function. You might consider to change the `[Average pay]` measure to

```
[Average pay] = DIVIDE([Salary], [Man-years])
```